# Incomplete migration banner

Tags: bug, migration

[This question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/990299/) was migrated from [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) to [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), as the [timeline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/990299/timeline) shows, but the migration banner does not include a link to the question on the original site ("Migrated from Russian Stack Exchange <date & time>"), as is normally the case:

[image]

It could be a localization issue, but I'm not sure; on [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/859760/223536) the banner works fine. [Here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1021392/223536) is another case where the question was migrated from the [ru.SO meta site](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the migration stub still redirects even though the ?noredirect=1 parameter is used?